# Vim pumvisible() is always 0

Tags: vim

I added this to my .vimrc file so I wouldn't be dropped to next line when pressing Enter to select suggestion from menu:
`inoremap <CR>=pumvisible() ? <C-Y> : <CR>`.

 But this has no effect. It's exactly same without that line except that now going to new line is slower so I guess that `pumvisible()` returns 0 every time.
I tried other combinations as well like putting `<expr>` before `<CR>` or using quotation marks and backslashes in `<C-Y> : <CR>` part but there is no difference. Without equals sign it just writes something like `pumvisble() something` (I can't remember exactly) if I press Enter in Insert mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? 'C-Y' : <CR>` just like [Ingo Karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332584/7952358). Unfortunately, this didn't work for me until I removed [vim-endwise](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) plugin. I don't know how, but removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Ah, that plugin probably hooks into the same `<CR>` mapping, and tries to restore the original one after it's done, but fails to recognize the `<expr>` part, so the mapping gets messed up. You could report that to the plugin's author; he could use `maparg(..., {dict})` to retrieve the `expr` flag.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing whitespace between the left-hand side (`<CR>`) and right-hand side (`=pumvisible`...) of the mapping. You've defined a mapping on `<CR>=pumvisible()`; that's why it has no effect and just makes Vim wait on pressing Enter.

Additionally, you've mixed up the syntax for `<expr>` and `<C-R>={expr}`. This one is easier with a `:help :map-expr`:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? '<C-Y>' : '<CR>'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I added `inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? '<C-Y> : <CR>'` to my .vimrc and now when I try choosing something from menu using Enter I get `choosencompletionpumvisible() ?  '' : ''` written.

Comment: It looks like `<expr>` part is not functional.